# How to symbolic link the files to new directory based on names in text file?

Tags: text-processing, symlink, xargs

I have a directory named `STRBAM`. In that, I have following `.bam` files that are `symbolic linked` from another directory.

```
Sample-CK-4952-01A-01D-1719-10.bam
Sample-A6-5656-01A-21D-A270-10.bam
Sample-AZ-4315-01A-01D-1408-10.bam
Sample-T9-A92H-01A-11D-A36X-10.bam
Sample-DY-A1H8-01A-21D-A152-10.bam
Sample-DC-5869-01A-01D-1657-10.bam
Sample-CI-6623-01B-11D-1826-10.bam
Sample-AA-3980-01A-02W-0995-10.bam
Sample-F4-6569-01A-11D-1771-10.bam
```

I also have a text file `All.txt` in the same directory with information like below:

```
    submitter_id                    Patient
Sample-CK-4952-01A-01D-1719-10  Sample-CK-4952
Sample-A6-5656-01A-21D-A270-10  Sample-A6-5656
Sample-AZ-4315-01A-01D-1408-10  Sample-AZ-4315
Sample-T9-A92H-01A-11D-A36X-10  Sample-T9-A92H
Sample-DY-A1H8-01A-21D-A152-10  Sample-DY-A1H8
Sample-DC-5869-01A-01D-1657-10  Sample-DC-5869
```

I have another directory `NEW`. I want to symbolic link only the `.bam` files using the information in `All.txt` file from directory `STRBAM`into the directory `New`

The output should look like below in the `New` directory:

```
Sample-CK-4952-01A-01D-1719-10.bam
Sample-A6-5656-01A-21D-A270-10.bam
Sample-AZ-4315-01A-01D-1408-10.bam
Sample-T9-A92H-01A-11D-A36X-10.bam
Sample-DY-A1H8-01A-21D-A152-10.bam
Sample-DC-5869-01A-01D-1657-10.bam
```

I tried the following `awk` with `xargs` command, but it didn't link only the required files I need using information from `All.txt` file instead it linked all the files.

```shell
awk 'NR > 1{ print $1 }' All.txt | xargs -I {} ln -s /path/to/STRBAM/* /path/to/New/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're linking all files in `/path/to/STRBAM/*` to `/path/to/New/` multiple times since you're using a `*` in the source path and not `{}`, i.e:

```
awk 'NR > 1{ print $1 }' All.txt | xargs -I{} ln -s /path/to/STRBAM/{}.bam /path/to/New/
```

If you want to add an additional check if the symlink exists in the source directory, you could use a small shell script and pass the source 
and destination directory as the first two positional parameters to the script:

```
awk 'NR > 1{ print $1 }' All.txt | xargs sh -c '
 src=$1; shift
 dest=$1; shift
 for i do
   if [ -h "$src/${i}.bam" ]; then
     ln -s "$src/${i}.bam" "$dest"
   fi
 done
' sh /path/to/STRBAM /path/to/New
```

Comment: thanq very much. small correction in your first answer. I guess `.bam` is not necessary. I used this and it worked `awk 'NR > 1{ print $1 }' All.txt | xargs -I{} ln -s /path/to/STRBAM/{} /path/to/New/`